# check in if ngmodel or forms are dirty or has input

Tags: angular, typescript, angular-material

how to check in angular if ngmodel or forms are dirty or has input using form fields but not using formgroup.

I wanted to check if 5 of the inputs fields has value or dirty I want to show like a message but how do we check if for example 5 fields from DealFields or ngModel dealDispositionFormFields are dirty or has inputs ? Thank you .

#tscode

```
    class DealDispositionFormFields {
      dealName:string;
      summary:string;
      dealDispositionType: string;
      terminationPayment:number;
      effectiveDate: string;
      totalBrokerCommission: number;
      effectiveDateString: string;
      dealId: number;
}
    
    @Component({
      selector: 'app-deal-idle-disposition',
      templateUrl: './deal-idle-disposition.component.html',
      styleUrls: ['./deal-idle-disposition.component.css']
    })
    export class DealIdleDispositionComponent implements OnInit {
           
             ngOnInit(): void {   
                this.dealDispositionFormFields = new DealDispositionFormFields();
              }
        
        checkIf5FieldsAreDirty() {
        ...
        }
```

#html code

```
<div id="deal-form-container" *ngIf="isEditing">
        <div id="deal-form-wizard-top" *ngIf="dealDispositionFormFields.dealDispositionType === 'Buyout'">
          <mat-form-field appearance="fill">
            <mat-label>Deal Name</mat-label>
            <input 
              matInput
              [(ngModel)]="dealDispositionFormFields.dealName"
              [required]="isExistingDeal">
          </mat-form-field>
          <mat-form-field appearance="fill">
            <mat-label>Summary of Deal</mat-label>
            <textarea 
              matInput
              class="resize-none"
              [(ngModel)]="dealDispositionFormFields.summary"
              [rows]="5"
              [required]="isExistingDeal">
            </textarea>
          </mat-form-field>
          <mat-form-field appearance="fill">
            <mat-label>Termination Payment</mat-label>
            <input 
              matInput
              (keyup) = "computeBuyout()"
              mask="separator.0" 
              thousandSeparator=","
              [allowNegativeNumbers]="false"
              [(ngModel)]="dealDispositionFormFields.terminationPayment"
              [required]="isExistingDeal">
              <span matPrefix *ngIf="dealDispositionFormFields.terminationPayment">$</span>
          </mat-form-field>
          <mat-form-field appearance="fill">
            <mat-label>Effective Date</mat-label>
              <input matInput
                (dateChange)="computeBuyout()"
                [matDatepicker]="effectiveDate" 
                [(ngModel)]="dealDispositionFormFields.effectiveDate"
                [required]="isExistingDeal">
              <mat-datepicker-toggle matSuffix [for]="effectiveDate"></mat-datepicker-toggle>
              <mat-datepicker #effectiveDate></mat-datepicker>
          </mat-form-field>
          <mat-form-field appearance="fill">
            <mat-label>Total Broker Commission</mat-label>
            <input 
              matInput
              (keyup) = "computeBuyout()"         
              mask="separator.0" 
              thousandSeparator=","
              [allowNegativeNumbers]="false"
              [(ngModel)]="dealDispositionFormFields.totalBrokerCommission"
              [required]="isExistingDeal">
              <span matPrefix *ngIf="dealDispositionFormFields.totalBrokerCommission">$</span>
          </mat-form-field>
        </div>
      </div>
```

Comment: Please refer to the documentation.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Check if input text field is dirty or not in Angular](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/65121510/check-if-input-text-field-is-dirty-or-not-in-angular)

Comment: No Sir , unfortunately

Comment: my code above does not use reactive form control nor form group

Comment: I see you are using NgModel, but what's preventing you to write the code for the constraints you mentioned above?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

ngModel has [dirty](https://angular.io/api/forms/NgModel) property as mentioned in this [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/54008278/12933302)

what you can do is use the `change` or `ngModelChange` events on each input

for example in your code it will be like

HTML

```
<mat-form-field appearance="fill">
            <mat-label>Deal Name</mat-label>
            <input 
              matInput
              [(ngModel)]="dealDispositionFormFields.dealName"
              [required]="isExistingDeal"
              (change)="checkIfDirty()">
</mat-form-field>
```

TS

```
   checkIfDirty() {
    let countDirtyValues = 0;
    Object.values(this.dealDispositionFormFields).map(value => {
      if (value) {
        countDirtyValues += 1;
      }
    });
    if (countDirtyValues >= 5) {
      // do something here
    }
  }
```

or if you want to find another solution. `ngmodel` is actually an instance of `formControl`, which in that case i would opt to create a reactive form as discribed in the angular documentation for formControl [here](https://angular.io/guide/reactive-forms#adding-a-basic-form-control) that can also be done without the need of a formGroup

Comment: Sir , is there a way on for example on your checkifdirty function to check if any fields as long as its morethan 5 fields that are dirty or has input ?

Comment: instead of doing it one by one , I wanted to check if 5 or morethan 5 fields are dirty

Comment: well if you absolutely must not use a reactive form i have edited the answer for you, basically the function now checks for each input inside your class if it has value it adds 1 until it gets to 5 so the condition is met, you can work with this

Comment: how do we reset a form field values ? like this.dealDispositionFormFields.reset()

Answer (score 0):

You should use angular's `Reactive Forms`. It has all the functionality you could want/need for form validation, plus it is easier to use.

Here is the official guide to using reactive forms: https://angular.io/guide/reactive-forms

in your component, you can create a FormGroup with controls like this:

```js
@Component({
      selector: 'app-deal-idle-disposition',
      templateUrl: './deal-idle-disposition.component.html',
      styleUrls: ['./deal-idle-disposition.component.css']
})
export MyComponent implements OnInit {
  myForm: FormGroup;
  constructor() {
    // create the form
    this.myForm = new FormGroup({
      name: new FormControl('', [Validators.required]),
      age: new FormControl(0, [Validators.required, Validators.min(18)])
    });
  }
}
```

According to the API docs (https://angular.io/api/forms/FormControl), the FormControl class extends `AbstractControl`, which has the `dirty` flag field/property. You can check a control's state like so:

```js
const nameControl = this.myForm.get('name'); // or this.myForm.controls['name'];
if (nameControl.dirty) {
  // ...
}
```

And you can listen to changes to the value of the control, similar to ngModel:

```js
nameControl.valueChanges.subscribe((newValue) => {
  // ...
});
```

Also you can listen to the status changes of the control, similar to ngModel:

```js
nameControl.statusChanges.subscribe((newStatus) => {
  // ...
});
```

Check out the official guide and the API docs; Angular does a great job on documenting their framework.